# Cannot root HTC One

Tags: rooting, adb, fastboot, htc, unrooting

I am following [this tutorial](http://htconeroot.com/htc-one-root/how-to-root-htc-one-windowsmaclinux/#comment-3887) to root my **HTC One M7**:

I fill the form [htcdev.com](http://htcdev.com) as described to get the file `Unlock_code.bin` sent by mail.

However, when entering in FASTBOOT mode

```
# fastboot flash unlocktoken Unlock_code.bin
```

I have a positive output on my terminal (see below) but nothing happens on my phone: I am still in the boot menu:

[image: Picture 1]

whereas I should get a screen with a message "Unlock bootloader?" directly after entering the command:

[image]

### **Where am I wrong and how to access this menu?**

**Terminal output**

```
# fastboot flash unlocktoken Unlock_code.bin
target reported max download size of 1514139648 bytes
sending ‘unlocktoken’ (0 KB)…
OKAY [ 0.141s]
writing ‘unlocktoken’…
(bootloader) unlock token check successfully
OKAY [ 0.004s]
finished. total time: 0.145s
```

---

**Fastboot Version**

```
# fastboot getvar all
(bootloader) version: 0.5
(bootloader) version-bootloader: 1.61.0000
(bootloader) version-baseband: 4T.35.3218.16
(bootloader) version-cpld: None
(bootloader) version-microp: None
(bootloader) version-main: ##########
(bootloader) version-misc: PVT SHIP S-ON
(bootloader) serialno: ############
(bootloader) imei: #############
(bootloader) meid: 00000000000000
(bootloader) product: m7_ul
(bootloader) platform: HBOOT-8064
(bootloader) modelid: #########
(bootloader) cidnum: #########
(bootloader) battery-status: good
(bootloader) battery-voltage: 4254mV
(bootloader) partition-layout: Generic
(bootloader) security: on
(bootloader) build-mode: SHIP
(bootloader) boot-mode: FASTBOOT
(bootloader) commitno-bootloader: ##########
(bootloader) hbootpreupdate: 11
(bootloader) gencheckpt: 0
all: Done!
finished. total time: 0.041s
```

Comment: This menu appears when you hit enter, I have no idea why nothing is happening to you.... Dumb question: Do you have the unlock token within the Fastboot folder?

Comment: Thank you for your help! No, the unlock token is in ~/Downloads and I am using `fastboot` installed with `apt-get install fastboot` on Linux. I should definelty try Windows.